# Transaction for several role grants

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, transactions

Can someone help me to make the behavior of the following code as one transaction?

```
params["user"]["userroles_attributes"].each do |key, value|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("GRANT " + params["user"]["userroles_attributes"][key.to_s]["role"] + " TO " + params["aioua"]["user_pk"])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to wrap the whole thing in a block with `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`.  There could be an issue since you are issuing commands via `execute` depending on what database you are using. The [ActiveRecord::Transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) documentation has a caveat listed for MySQL.

Hope this helps!